# JQuery return a function to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to set a variable equal to a function, but instead of the variable being equal to the function it is equal to the functions return value?

Searched for a bit on this without any success, it is most likely because I don't know how to phrase the question, but any help is appreciated, this is what I have :

Instead of having to set `var ztype = zoom()` after the function, is there anyway for me to assign the return value to `zoom` without an extra line of code?

```
var zoom = function(){ //can be set to Full / percentage / Image / left empty for native image size
    var type = $('.carousel').attr('data-zoom');
    if(!type){
        type = $(that).attr('data-zoom');
    }

    return type;
}
var ztype = zoom();
```

Comment: You can define ztype as global variable, then you can access it inside the function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're trying to set a variable to the result of a function. This should do what you're hoping for;

```
var ztype = function(){ //can be set to Full / percentage / Image / left empty for native image size
    var type = $('.carousel').attr('data-zoom');
    if(!type){
        type = $(that).attr('data-zoom');
    }

    return type;
}();
```

Comment: ahhh, so thats what the `()` at the end of the function will do?

Comment: @Adjit It will execute the function immediatly

Comment: Yeah, that will call the function immediately

Comment: Awesome, didn't know exactly how to phrase the question but I'm glad you guys understood. Thanks, I'll accept when I can